# SSRS - OutOfMemory exception for Matrix report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to design a `Matrix` report through SSRS to aggregate a column for a range of dynamic values in another column (i.e. a pivot). This data consists of just over 13 million rows, so it's a large dataset.

When doing a `PIVOT` on this data via T-SQL, it's able to aggregate all of these rows in about ~1min, however when getting SSRS to do the pivoting for me through a `Matrix` report, I'm getting an OutOfMemory exception when trying to preview the report on my PC.

The query returning the dataset itself isn't complicated, it's as simple as:

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,Test_Ref
    ,Data_issue_indicator
FROM MyTable
```

Where we're trying to do the sum of `Data_issue_indicator` (which can be either a `1` or `0`) for values in `Test_Ref`, in which there is a dynamic range of values to aggregate against; in other words we cannot use a standard `Tablix` report because the amount of columns can increase at any time should a new `Test_Ref` value be introduced into the dataset.

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019, and my PC is a Windows 10, i7-8850H, with 16GB memory.

Is there a suggestion on getting around this issue?

Comment: Have you tried aggregating the data your dataset rather than having the report do all the work? You can keep the report design the same (probably) just change the dataset query to be `SELECT Test_Ref, SUM(Data_issue_indicator) AS Data_issue_indicator FROM myTable GROUP BY Test_Ref`

Comment: @AlanSchofield This helped slightly in terms of reducing rows returned from ~13m to ~6m, however this was still too much to handle for SSRS; at least in my environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using SSRS, its recommended to grab more data once in case of using the dataset multiple times. but when you have a larger dataset it needs to be a trade off between what you want to achieve against do you need all the data.

So in this situation i would suggest to use a procedure to restrict the amount of data that you are grabbing to the report.

I have gone through this sort of scenario, and i had to do the same, because its not the query that is timing out but the huge amount of data that is loaded to the report which fails the report.

If you have SQL server profiler , you would see the SQL executed and completed, but the report times out rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas, assuming that you plan to deploy the report to a server that will have the memory to handle this, and that you'd prefer to do this processing on the report server rather than the SQL server for some reason:

1. Don't test the functionality on your PC in Visual Studio.   Design the report, deploy it to your Report Server, and test it there to see if it works.
2. When testing on your PC, force it somehow to use a much smaller dataset:  one just large enough to verify that the pivoting Matrix works, but small enough that your PC's memory can handle it.

Or better yet, do option 2, and then option 1.

Comment: It needs to be done on the report server because the number of columns could change, meaning if a new column appears from a `PIVOT` on SQL Servers side, I would have to go and change the report definition to include that new column manually. The idea is that the Matrix report is able to automatically handle that without having a developer to manually change the report definition.